# Cordova InAppBrowser - Open popups from web within the InAppBrowser container

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I have a mobile app that opens external URL links within the App by using InAppBrowser (IAB).

However, when the web I open in IAB contains a link that would normally open in a popup/second window, this doesn't get loaded/displayed.

Is this just not supported by IAB?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override:

`web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){new WebChromeClient (){}}`

in your `MainActivity.java`.This will force all `url` to be open in your `IAB`.

Comment: Is this in the InAppBrowser.java class?

Comment: This is a setting you have to pass in your activity having Android Webview.