# Cordova InAppBrowser support for popups in the inappbrowser container

Tags: cordova, popup, braintree, inappbrowser

I have a mobile app which uses an inappbrowser allowing a user to login to their account. In their account they have documents, mainly pdfs, which open in the form of a popup window.

Unfortunately this doesn't work in the inappbrowser. I've looked into using cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-popup-bridge but this browser just adds support for Braintree PopupBridge libraries, meaning that it would require code changes on the server side.

I've searched online and their doesn't appear to be any work arounds (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40003864/6423552 this one here doesn't give much detail). Does anyone know of any solutions/workarounds to open popups in the inappbrowser?

Thanks,
S

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?